# Mysql query ( LINK tickets, employee , cats , comments ) using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

here is my tables

**Tickets**

```
 tic_id,       
 tic_cat      
 tic_priority 
 tic_cus      
 tic_date     
 tic_title    
 tic_msg      
 tic_files    
 tic_emp      
 tic_moved    
 tic_statue   
 tic_rate
```

**Employee**

```
 emp_id       
 emp_name     
 emp_username 
 emp_password 
 emp_cat      
 emp_special  
 emp_lastlogin
 emp_session  
 emp_code     
 emp_statue   
 emp_master   
 emp_ip
```

**Cats**

```
 cat_id      
 cat_type    
 cat_name    
 cat_statue  
 cat_delete  
 cat_date    
 cat_ip      
 cat_options
```

**Comments**

```
  com_id     
  tic_id     
  cus_id     
  emp_id     
  com_msg    
  com_time   
  com_ip     
  com_statue
```

And I need the result as

```
 tic_id | tic_cat | cat_name | tic_title | tic_statue | tic_priority | tic_msg | emp_name | comments_row | last_comment |
```

I Make this query but i have 2 problems

Query Is

```
SELECT
      tickets.tic_id
      ,tickets.tic_cat
      ,cats.cat_name
      ,tickets.tic_title
      ,tic_statue
      ,tic_priority
      ,tickets.tic_msg
      ,employee.emp_name
      ,count(comments.com_id)
      ,( SELECT comments.com_msg
            from comments
                 order by com_id DESC limit 1 )
          AS last_comment
      FROM tickets
      LEFT JOIN employee
                  on (tickets.tic_emp = employee.emp_id)
      LEFT join cats
                  on (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
      LEFT JOIN comments
                  on(tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id)

  WHERE tic_cus=2 /* 2 -> This Is Customer Id */
  GROUP BY comments.tic_id
```

My Problems Is

i have 3 Result In Database To Customer Number 2  ->  only show   2 results

i want to get  Last Comment                       ->  the 2 Result have the same last comment

How Can i do this Query With Out This 2 Errors

**Edit The Post After New Query**

Problem number Two Solved Using This Query

```
SELECT
      tickets.tic_id
      ,tickets.tic_cat
      ,cats.cat_name
      ,tickets.tic_title
      ,tic_statue
      ,tic_priority
      ,tickets.tic_msg
      ,employee.emp_name
      ,count(comments.com_id)
      ,( SELECT comments.com_msg
            from comments
                 WHERE tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id
                 order by com_id DESC limit 1 )
          AS last_comment
      FROM tickets
      LEFT JOIN employee
                  on (tickets.tic_emp = employee.emp_id)
      LEFT join cats
                  on (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
      LEFT JOIN comments
                  on(tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id)

  WHERE tic_cus=2
  GROUP BY comments.tic_id
```

**Solved**

```
SELECT
      tickets.tic_id
      ,tickets.tic_cat
      ,cats.cat_name
      ,tickets.tic_title
      ,tic_statue
      ,tic_priority
      ,tickets.tic_msg
      ,employee.emp_name
      ,count(comments.com_id)
      ,( SELECT comments.com_msg
            from comments
                 WHERE tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id
                 order by com_id DESC limit 1 )
          AS last_comment
      FROM tickets
      LEFT JOIN employee
                  on (tickets.tic_emp = employee.emp_id)
      LEFT join cats
                  on (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
      LEFT JOIN comments
                  on(tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id)

  WHERE tic_cus=2
  GROUP BY tickets.tic_id
```

Comment: @Gordon: Note that you removed OP content with your last edit.

Comment: @mellamokb yeah, I was probably looking at the very first version before the OP edited that in. thanks for readding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Can you show some data in these tables to demonstrate?  In other words, how do you know you should have three records?  Does `select * from tickets where tic_cus = 2` by itself return 3 records?

2) You need to filter the comments subquery by ticket.  I would also recommend having the comment count in a subquery as well and leave out the `GROUP BY` altogether:

```
,( select count(comments.com_id)
     from comments
    where comments.tic_id = tickets.tic_id) as comment_count

,( select comments.com_msg
     from comments
    where comments.tic_id = tickets.tic_id
          ^^^^^^^ filter by ticket so not last of ALL comments
 order by com_id DESC limit 1) as last_comment
```

Comment: Thank you @mellamokb , The problem solved , see my post after edit :)

Comment: Your Query help me to find the problem   i was group the comment_row but i should group ticket_tic_id :)